# Keras + tf.Dataset + predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm using a Dataset that contains both Numerical + categorical data.
Before training and evaluation I convert the categorical features to numeric and I end up having the same number of features, just numeric:

Based on this Notebook:

https://www.kaggle.com/jannesklaas/explaining-income-classification-with-keras/notebook

My model is using keras + Estimator (model_to_estimator) which defines a Training and Serving function.

Total features: 14

- My training dataset, contains 14.
- My evaluation dataset contains 14.

Input function:

```
  def input_fn(features, labels, shuffle, num_epochs, batch_size):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))    
    if shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=256)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset
```

If I want to do real predictions, data needs to be converted to numeric?

```
25, Private, 226802, 11th, 7, Never-married, Machine-op-inspct, Own-child, Black, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
```

This is the estimator serving function:

```
train_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(features=X_train, 
                    labels=Y_train, 
                    shuffle=True, 
                    num_epochs=10, 
                    batch_size=40)

estimator.train(train_input_fn)
```

Reference [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras)

How to create a function to be able to pass predictions?

Comment: your data should be numeric yes. The estimator methods create a new graph. So you can use your input_fn for the evaluation as well by making it more generic and passing X_test and Y_test to the function or you can write a new function that does this.

Comment: This function will not contain the target correct ?

Comment: you can have the target as well. The predict method would only take the first item when your function returns data which is of tuples

Comment: Thanks, can you upgrade your comment to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data should be numeric. The estimator methods construct the graph for their associated input functions, so you can either make the current input_fn more generic to be able to return the test dataset as well by just feeding X_test and Y_test or you can write a new method that does this. The target can be passed to the predict method, as it will take the first item only in case the inputs are in form of tuple.